# Ruby: how do I recursively find and remove empty directories?

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to write some ruby that would recursively search a given directory for all empty child directories and remove them.

Thoughts?

Note: I'd like a script version if possible. This is both a practical need and a something to help me learn.

Comment: first thought: system "find . -type d | xargs rmdir -p 2>/dev/null"

Comment: Just a note, I don't want to do this operation in one shot from the command line. Its going to be in a ruby script. What you have above is a cmd line version no?

Comment: well, it's a shell command, yes, but invoked from within ruby using `Kernel.system` ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In ruby:

```
Dir['**/*']                                            \
  .select { |d| File.directory? d }                    \
  .select { |d| (Dir.entries(d) - %w[ . .. ]).empty? } \
  .each   { |d| Dir.rmdir d }
```

Comment: could you explain the "-" in line 3?

Comment: I'm subtracting the array containing the strings "." and ".." from the array of directory entries, since every directory contains those two special entries.

Comment: also, could you explain what are the "\"s are for? line continuation? are they needed?

Comment: They're line continuation, yes. They're not needed if you put the dot at the end of the previous line, but I like them at the beginning to make it clear that this line is continuing from the previous. (Although really, I just formatted as such for SO display purposes. I generally leave these things in a single line, up to ~160 chars or so. Some people hate me, yes. I think they're using TTYs.)

Comment: haha. Thanks kch you saved me some time. I had all the doco pulled up, but was missing part of the bigger picture to put it all together.

Comment: You see, the way I wrote the code, if I dropped the \s, ruby could interpret the line as a complete expression, and so it would.

Comment: you have to delete in reverse order, otherwise you won't delete all empty directories

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the examples from kch, dB. and Vishnu above, I've put together a one-liner that I think is a more elegant solution:

```
Dir['**/'].reverse_each { |d| Dir.rmdir d if Dir.entries(d).size == 2 }
```

I use `'**/'` instead of `'/**/*'` for the glob, which only returns directories, so I don't have to test whether it's a directory later. I'm using `reverse_each` instead of `sort.reverse.each` as it's shorter and supposedly more efficient, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859587/why-array-reverse-each-is-faster-than-array-reverse-each). I prefer `Dir.entries(d).size == 2` to `(Dir.entries(d) - %w[ . .. ]).empty?` because it's a little easier to read and understand, although `(Dir.entries(d) - %w[ . .. ]).empty?` would probably work better if you had to run your script on Windows.

I've tested this quite a bit on Mac OS X and it works well, even with recursive empty directories.

Comment: A very elegant compilation of solutions.

Comment: Nice refactor but I think mentioning . and .. is more intuitive than size==2 so I would go with ` Dir['lib/**/'].reverse_each { |d| Dir.rmdir d if Dir.entries(d).sort==%w(. ..) }`

Comment: Yeah, that kind of is more intuitive.

Comment: Nice approach, I'd go for the following these days: `Dir['**/'].reverse_each { |d| Dir.rmdir(d) if Dir.empty?(d) }` or even shorter `Dir['**/'].reverse_each { Dir.rmdir(_1) if Dir.empty?(_1) }`. However, you should note that this solution builds an array of all directories in memory, so you must not use it but in case you know that the number of directories (all, not just the empty ones) is limited.

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete in reverse order, otherwise if you have an empty directory foo with a subdirectory bar you will delete bar, but not foo.

```
  Dir.glob(dir + "/**/*").select { |d| 
    File.directory?(d)
  }.reverse_each { |d| 
    if ((Dir.entries(d) - %w[ . .. ]).empty?)
      Dir.rmdir(d)
    end
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use shell?

> find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' \;

Does exactly what you want.

Comment: I was hoping for a ruby script version to help grasp working with files. I could invoke the above with 'sh <your cmd>' from a rake script I suppose. Got a script version?

Comment: The script command would be exactly the same. However, the below post has an answer that will suit you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir['/Users/path/Movies/incompleteAnime/foom/**/*']. \
select { |d| File.directory? d }. \
sort.reverse. \
each {|d| Dir.rmdir(d) if Dir.entries(d).size ==  2}
```

just like the first example, but the first example doesn't seem to handle the recursive bit. The sort and reverse ensures we deal with the most nested directories first.

I suppose sort.reverse could be written as `sort {|a,b| b <=> a}` for efficiency

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir.glob('**/*').each do |dir|
  begin
    Dir.rmdir dir if File.directory?(dir)
  # rescue # this can be dangereous unless used cautiously
  rescue Errno::ENOTEMPTY
  end
end
```

Comment: Rescuing from any exception willy-nilly is not the best idea in real production code.

Comment: Usually, I'd have to agree, but this is sort of a borderline situation. In any case, I updated the rescue statement.

Comment: Yea, it's one of these things that's fine as long as you know what you're doing. But one googler hitting this page might be looking into it just for a quick script, or for a library that'll have a major role in a filesystem intensive application. So, basically, n00bs get the safe code by default, and people who supposedly know what they're doing will do so at their own risk.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this script on OS X, but if you are on Windows, you'll need to make changes.

You can find the files in a directory, including hidden files, with Dir#entries.

This code will delete directories which become empty once you've deleted any sub-directories.

```
def entries(dir)
  Dir.entries(dir) - [".", ".."]
end

def recursively_delete_empty(dir)
  subdirs = entries(dir).map { |f| File.join(dir, f) }.select { |f| File.directory? f }
  subdirs.each do |subdir|
    recursively_delete_empty subdir
  end

  if entries(dir).empty?
    puts "deleting #{dir}"
    Dir.rmdir dir
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module MyExtensions
  module FileUtils
    # Gracefully delete dirs that are empty (or contain empty children).
    def rmdir_empty(*dirs)
      dirs.each do |dir|
        begin
          ndel = Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).count do |d|
            begin; Dir.rmdir d; rescue SystemCallError; end
          end
        end while ndel > 0
      end
    end
  end

  module ::FileUtils
    extend FileUtils
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pure shell solution, I found this very useful

```
  find "$dir" -depth -type d |
    while read sub; do
      [ "`cd "$sub"; echo .* * ?`" = ". .. * ?" ] || continue
      echo rmdir "$sub"
      #rmdir "$sub"
    done
```

But if you have gnu-find installed (not universal yet)...

```
  find . -depth -type d -empty -printf "rmdir %p\n"
```

this uses find with xargs...

```
  find . -depth -type d -print0 |
    xargs -0n1 sh -c '[ "`cd "$0"; echo .* * ?`" = ". .. * ?" ] &&
                        echo "rmdir $0";'
```

Comment: That's really cool. I originally looked for a Ruby solution, but it's very handy to do it in BASH if Ruby is not installed on a system.  Thanks!