# is ruby on rails supporting folder hiearachy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i using ruby on rails programing language for the making a very simple project which is need to create folder hierarchy just like yahoomail folder. but i need to also subfolder create in this directory so is support ruby on rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

You can create recursive directories using

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.mkdir_p 'my/path/to/something'
```

Following links can be useful for you
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Ruby,
[Ruby: how do I recursively find and remove empty directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290670/ruby-how-do-i-recursively-find-and-remove-empty-directories)