# Why Array.reverse_each is faster than Array.reverse.each

Tags: ruby, arrays

I hardly use `reverse_each` method, instead I call upon `reverse.each` when I need to traverse an array backwards. So I just did some benchmarking and apparently `reverse_each` is significantly faster than `reverse.each`.

- Is this because there is an element of time associated with creating a reverse array before iterating through it when using `reverse.each`?

However in my example (below) of 10 million iterations `TIME(reverse) + TIME(each) - TIME(reverse.each) ~ 1.2 seconds` for an array of size 4. And this time difference more or less stays stable irrespective of the size of array. I have tested it for upto 100 elements.

- What accounts for this one second difference?

---

```
require 'benchmark'

number = 10000000
arr = (1..4).to_a

Benchmark.bm(13) do |x|
    x.report("reverse.each") { number.times { arr.reverse.each {|x| x} } }
    x.report("reverse_each") { number.times { arr.reverse_each {|x| x} } }
    x.report("reverse")      { number.times { arr.reverse } }             
    x.report("each")         { number.times { arr.each {|x| x} } }        
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would definitely say it has to do with the time associating with creating the reverse array! You've only tried really small arrays (an array with 100 elements is still a small array). If you try with bigger arrays (for instance 10k elements), I think you will really notice the difference.

Comment: same answer, even faster :) +1

Answer (score 23):

It's pretty straight forward:

- `reverse.each` creates a new array then loops each element
- `reverse_each` loops in reverse order (no intermediate array created)

See source code in doc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this is only the case for Arrays, other Enumerables, including Hash, *do* create an intermediate Array for #reverse_each ([see source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each)), so it doesn't save any time for those.